# Full height a bootstrap col contain only a fixed element

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm making a left side by bootstrap and have this problem when set my inner element fixed position.

this is my HTML

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3 left">
            <left-side></left-side>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 center"></div>
        <div class="col-md-3 right">
            <right-side></right-side>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

the problem is in col-md-3 left class, leftSide directive has fixed position and so the left class has height 1px only. So the col-md-6 class hides my leftSide directive 
Now I want the left class height fit the leftSide directive height. Don't care about the rightSide.
I tried with left:after but it didn't work.
Thanks. 
This is what it looks like

[image]

Comment: are you using bootstrap v3 or v4 and can you fiddle it? or add your css (left,center and right classes)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `height: 100vh;` and `overflow: scroll;` to apply height like this:

```css
.container-fluid{
  background: #ccc;
  min-height: 100vh;
}
.left left-side{
  width: 25%;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index:1;
  overflow: scroll;
  height: 100vh;
  background: #fff;
}
ul{
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}
ul li{
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 left">
            <left-side>
              <ul>
              <li>Menu</li>
              <li>Menu</li>
              <li>Menu</li>
              <li>Menu</li>
              <li>Menu</li>
              <li>Menu</li>
              <li>Menu</li>
              <li>Menu</li>
              <li>Menu</li>
              <li>Menu</li>
              <li>Menu</li>
              <li>Menu</li>
              <li>Menu</li>
              <li>Menu</li>
              <li>Menu</li>
              </ul>
            </left-side>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 center">
            <p>
      Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
           </p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 right">
            <right-side></right-side>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here I used bootstrap 3.3.7 (You can change any other version) and can also check this [Fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/kjquoqna/2/)

Comment: but when set position of .left  is fixed, when the screen smaller, the next col-md-6 will hide this class

Comment: thanks. I checked this Fiddle. But when I use Angular directive inside the left class it's not work, It's fine if not directive. maybe .left don't know it has directive inside

Comment: Do you have any working demo? Which you can share somewhere.